# Get double number without scientific notation that not using NumberFormat in Java

Tags: java

Responsibility of my Web service is getting KPI of an system. These KPI is double numbers. When i get these numbers, they are large number contain scientific notation (E). I knew that i can format it to string to remove E. But i want these number are double type for clients can calculate when they get data from my web service. So, can anyone show me the solution to get these numbers in double type without E. Please help me
P/S: Don't suggest me use format or any method like that. I don't want get String type

Comment: Numbers do not have an inherent format. A `double` variable does not have a format. The format is determined by the code that displays the number.

Comment: What @Jesper said. Show your XSD, code, whatever. Otherwise, you're not going to get any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use BigDecimal instead of double.